# Can't find .py files for new doctypes

Tags: doctype, frappe

Complete newbie here. Built a new site and a new app. Installed the new app. Want to add a custom script, but can't find the ".py" files for the doctypes I created.

The "Custom?" checkbox is left checked and greyed out.
I am logged in as an administrator and I set the site developer_mode config to 1.

(I know I can add custom scripts from the gui, but still, it's sometimes more convenient to work on my own IDE).

Basicaly I want to create a table as a child ("Reciepe") of a doctype ("Dishes"). The table should have a data field (`quantity`) and a select field (`raw_material`). I want to populate the `raw_material` with `var_name` field from another doctype ("Raw Materials", which also has their prices, thus allowing me to calculate the cost of each dish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `sites` directory, there will be `site_config.json` file. Ensure `developer_mode` is present in that file.

```
$ cat sites/dev.localhost/site_config.json
```

Clear the cache b running

```
$ bench clear-cache
```

After that, go to Browser console and verify `developer_mode`, `user`.

[image]

If these 2 values are shown correctly in browser console, then `Custom?` will be unchecked and `.py` files will be generated.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. However, trying frappe.boot.developer_mode returned an error: module 'frappe' has no attribute 'boot. Is this normal or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [tutorial](https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en/tutorial/create-a-doctype) and created the app "library_management". The py-files were created here:
/home/myuser/frappe-bench/apps/library_management/library_management/library_management/doctype

Answer (score 0):

Switch to development mode and login to desk as admin. Then go to doctype and deselect "Custom?" in doctype settings. And then save the doctype again. Now you should see the related doctype files in your IDE.